Characterization of normal Fredholm Operators
I'm working on the following problem, but I'm getting stuck on the last part.  Here is the problem:

Let $T \in \mathcal{B}(H)$ be normal.  Prove $T$ is Fredholm if and only if $0$ isn't a limit point of $\sigma(T)$ and $\dim(\ker(T)) < \infty$.

So the backwards direction is simple enough using spectral measures.  For the forward direction, if I assume $T$ is Fredholm, then obviously $\dim(\ker(T)) < \infty$, so I just need to prove that $0$ is an isolated point of $\sigma(T)$.  Note $E(\{0\}) \neq 0$, otherwise since $T$ is normal, we would have $\text{Index}(T) = 0$ and thus by the Fredholm alternative we would have $T$ is invertible, which contradicts that $0 \in \sigma(T)$.  Thus $E(\{0\}) \neq 0$.  This is almost what I want, since if $0$ is isolated, it must be an eigenvalue, but the converse need not be true I don't think (right)?
So I start by assuming for contradiction that $0$ is a limit point of the spectrum, and let $E$ be the associated spectral measure associated to $T$.  Then since $\sigma_p(T)$ is dense in $\sigma(T)$, I may assume that I have an infinite sequence of distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_n \longrightarrow 0$.  Then in particular given any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lambda_n \in B_{\frac{1}{k}}(0)$ for all $n \geq N$.  In particular then since each $\lambda_n$ is an eigenvalue: $$0 \neq E(\{\lambda_n\}) \leq E(B_{\frac{1}{k}}(0))$$ since $\chi_{\{\lambda_n\}} \leq \chi_{B_{\frac{1}{k}}(0)}$ for all $n \geq N$.  Hence, there are an infinite sequence $(x_n)_n \subset E(B_{\frac{1}{k}}(0))(H)$ of eigenvectors with $x_n \in E(\{\lambda_n\})(H) = \ker(\lambda_n I-T)$.  Moreover for $i,j \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $$E(\{\lambda_i\})E(\{\lambda_j\}) = E(\{\lambda_i\} \cap \{\lambda_j\})$$ so that the ranges $E(\{\lambda_n\})(H)$ are mutually orthogonal and thus $(x_n)_n \subset E(B_{\frac{1}{k}}(0))(H)$ contains an infinite linearly independent set, and thus is infinite dimensional for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$.  However we also have that $\chi_{B_{\frac{1}{k}}(0)} \downarrow \chi_{\{0\}}$ pointwise, and since the Borel functional calculus preserves monotone sequential pointwise limits in the strong operator topology, we have $$E(B_{\frac{1}{k}}(0)) \longrightarrow E(\{0\}) \in \mathcal{B}_f(H) \: \: \text{in the strong operator topology}.$$
I wanted to aim for a contradiction by arguing that since each projection $E(B_{\frac{1}{k}}(0))$ is infinite rank that $E(\{0\})$ must be infinite rank too, but I don't think this is true, since the convergence is in the SOT, and not in norm.  If this was in norm, then by Reisz' lemma I think this would fail.

Assume $T$ is a normal Fredholm operator. Then $\ker T=\ker T^*$. We have the orthogonal decomposition $\mathcal{H}=\ker T\oplus  {\rm Im}\,T,$ and both subspaces are $T$  invariant. The operator $T$ restricted to ${\rm Im}\,T$ is invertible. Thus there is $\delta>0$ such that $\lambda I-T$ restricted to ${\rm Im}\,T$ is invertible for any $|\lambda|<\delta.$ If $0<|\lambda |<\delta$ the operator $\lambda I-T$ is equal $\lambda I$ on $\ker T$ and $\lambda I-T$ on  $ {\rm Im}\,T.$ As the subspaces are orthogonal to each other the operator $\lambda I-T$ is invertible for $0<|\lambda|<\delta.$
Conversely, we have $\ker T=\ker T^*.$ It suffices to show that ${\rm Im}\,T$ is closed as $\sigma(\widetilde{T})\cup \{0\}=\sigma(T)\cup \{0\}.$ To this end we will  show that $\widetilde{T}$ is invertible, as this would imply
$$\|Tx\|=\|\widetilde{T}x\|\ge c\|x\|,\quad x\in {\rm Im}\,T$$ hence ${\rm Im}\,T={\rm Im}\,\widetilde{T}$ would be closed.ed. Assume  $0$ is not a limit point of $\sigma(T).$ We have the orthogonal decomposition $\mathcal{H}=\ker T\oplus\overline{{\rm Im}\,T}.$ Let $\widetilde{T}$ denote the restriction of $T$ to $\overline{{\rm Im}\,T}.$ Then $\widetilde{T}$ is a normal operator such that $\ker\widetilde{T}=\{0\}.$ Moreover  $0$ is not a limit point of $\sigma(T).$
